In "Oliver Twist", how did Nancy eavesdrop in Fagin's den when she was at Sikes' house?
In chapter 26 of Charles Dickens' novel Oliver Twist, shortly after Sikes' burglary attempt at Miss Mayile's house goes awry, Fagin visits the Three Cripples bar, informs the landlord to pass on a message to Monks to meet him at his den. Then he sets off to Sikes' house where he finds Nancy alone. A fight ensues, when Nancy expresses relief, Oliver is better off dead, thus irking Fagin. In a rage, Fagin splutters that Oliver is worth hundreds of pounds and he would hang Sikes if he loses the boy because of him. Then he stops, aware he was giving way too much information. Then he gets up to go. Nancy's head falls back upon the table and she seems to lapse once more into a stupor. Now, Fagin is back in his den when Monk comes up behind him. There, they retire to an empty room up the stairs and discuss about the recent failed coup. And, suddenly Monks exclaims that there is a shadow of a woman on the wall, in a bonnet and cloak, bending forward to listen. The candle flame flutters in the gust of air caused by the opening of the door and they find no one there.
Here, Nancy who went to sleep after Fagin left, how did she end up in Fagin's den? Did she follow Fagin all way through? There is no mentioning of her taking up that arduous task. Is it an oversight by the novel's author and he put it her there because the story needed it?

It's a long time since I read the book, but was Monk perhaps imagining it?

that can't be. Nancy confides to Rose, she listened to Fagin & Monks' talks twice. One refers to the talk after the burglary attempt goes kaput where monks sneers at fagin for not yet training oliver as a thief. Another one, when sikes sends nancy to fagin's house to collect some money. That was after, Monks had met the Bumble's couple, collected the locket & thrown into the roaring river. And he boasts to Fagin, that the only proofs of Oliver's identity lie at the bottom of the river.
